# Is there a Cloudfoundry API to create/retrieve service keys?

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am trying to automate the cloudfoundry deployments but couldn't find any API to work with service keys. 
Is there any Cloudfoundry API to perform below operations -

```
1. cf create-service-key <my-service-name> <my-access-key-name>
2. cf service-key <my-service-name> <my-access-key-name>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. POST /v2/service_keys (see http://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/263/service_keys/create_a_service_key.html)
2. GET /v2/service_keys/:guid (see http://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/263/service_keys/retrieve_a_particular_service_key.html)

You can retrieve the service instance guid using `cf service your-service-instance --guid`.